# What is "net" in HDL synthesis

Tags: verilog, hdl, synthesis

I am a beginner in circuit synthesis, and I came across the word **net** a lot, but I am never able to find its standard definition. It seems to me that it refers to any kind of "black box" where it receives inputs and produce outputs. So it can be a sub circuit inside a big circuit and it can be an array of gates. Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 8):

No, your understanding is not correct.

**Verilog**

In Verilog, *net* has a precise definition:

IEEE 1800-2012 states:

> **6.5 Nets and variables**
>
> There are two main groups of data objects: variables and nets. These two groups differ in the way in which they
>   are assigned and hold values.
>
> A net can be written by one or more
>   continuous assignments, by primitive outputs, or through module ports.
>   **The resultant value of multiple drivers is determined by the
>   resolution function of the net type.** A net cannot be procedurally
>   assigned.

A net can be one of many types, for example: `wire`, `supply0`, `wand`, but by far the most common type is `wire`.

IEEE 1800-2012 goes on to say:

> Variables can be written by one or more procedural statements,
>   including procedural continuous assignments. **The last write determines
>   the value.** Alternatively, variables can be written by one continuous
>   assignment or one port.

The main difference between the behaviour of a variable and a net is their behaviour when assigned to from more than one place, as highlighted by the bold text in the two quotes:

**For a net**, if you assign to it from more than one place, its resulting value is determined by a *resolution function*, which for the built-in net types (`wire` etc). The behaviour of the resolution function depends on the net type and that is the difference between the net types. So, for example, with a `wire`, if both `1'b0` and `1'b1` are assigned to it, the resulting value will be `1'bx` (unknown) if both assignments assign values with the same *strength*. The resolution function is intended to model real electronics. (There is also the added complication of user-defined net types and drive strengths, but let's leave those out for this discussion.)

**For a variable**, if you assign to it from more than one place, its resulting value is determined by whatever value is written last (just like a normal software variable). So, for example, if a `1'b0` is assigned and then a `1'b1` is assigned, the resulting value will be `1'b1` because that value was assigned last. There is no resolution function involved nor any concept of drive strength.

Both nets and variables are used to model combinational logic and sequential logic. There are rules for when you can use a net and when you can use a variable and the choice of which to use is governed by those rules (given in the quotes above). These were strict in verilog, but have been relaxed in System-Verilog to such an extent that, if you are not designing using tri-state logic, you don't need nets in System-Verilog.

VHDL has exactly the same distinction. The VHDL equivalent of a Verilog net is a *signal*; the VHDL equivalent of a Verilog variable is a *variable*. The rules about which to use where in VHDL are different, however, and more strict (no surprise there).

**Electronics**

In electronics a *net* means a piece of metal through which current flows. In other words, a net is the connection between one place and another. Physically, it could be a PCB track, a cable, a bond wire or a metal connection on an IC. Generally, in digital electronics, it is most like to be a metal connection on an IC.

**Synthesis**

So, to answer your question, if someone uses the term "net" when talking about the output of a logic synthesiser (the *gate-level netlist*), they almost certainly mean the second idea: the construct in whatever format that gate-level netlist uses that models the connection between one gate and another. As it is common for synthesisers to output their gate-level netlist as Verilog, those connections between gates are probably modeled using *Verilog nets* anyway (probably `wire`s).